Needing to apply a Strapi Menu to all Pages
Using the Strapi Menu Plugin, I am attempting to add a Strapi Menu to all pages for my site. When using the "await fetch('/api/example-menu/1?populate=*')" in my middleware file, it causes a 500 error when I view the json for a page on the site.
Therefore, my question is, what do I need to add to my middleware file in order for the Strapi Menu Plugin to populate its data on my site pages?
The specific plugin I am using is https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-menus
Per the plugin documentation, I have tried adding the "await fetch('/api/example-menu/1?populate=');" to my middleware file, but I get a 500 error when viewing the json. The only way I have been able to view the json data from the menu plugin is by using that same await fetch code, but only on the menu api call, not on the site page api call. As in, if I go to "http://localhost:1337/api/example-menu/1?populate=" I can see the menu data, but I need to see the menu data when I go to one of my site pages such as "http://localhost:1337/api/example-page" and right now I only see the page data, but it does not include the menu data.


module.exports = (config, { strapi }) => {
  // Add your own logic here.
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    strapi.log.info('In example-page middleware.');
      ctx.query = {
        populate,
        ...ctx.query,
      }
    await fetch('/api/example-menu/1?populate=*');
    await next();
  };
};



